# How to make Typed Racket's type checker faster?

Tags: racket, typed-racket

Racket is fast. But when I use Typed Racket and run the code , I find that the type checker is slow.

For example , run this code from [The Typed Racket Guide](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/beginning.html)

```scm
#lang typed/racket

(struct: pt ([x : Real] [y : Real]))

(: distance (-> pt pt Real))
(define (distance p1 p2)
  (sqrt (+ (sqr (- (pt-x p2) (pt-x p1)))
           (sqr (- (pt-y p2) (pt-y p1))))))
```

The type checker needs 4-6 seconds to work on my computer (i7, 4g ram)

I tried a different computer and it's all the same

Did I make some mistake? How can I make type checker faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's not anything you can really change to make the type checker run faster. If you use `#lang typed/racket/base` instead of `#lang typed/racket`, things might be a bit faster. But for a variety of reasons, Typed Racket's typechecker has to solve some hard problems, and thus isn't that fast.